# What is the proper way to refer to the SQL dialect used by Microsoft Access?

Tags: ms-access, jet-sql

I'm converting some SQL that came from Microsoft Access into T-SQL, and I'm making note of these changes in my documentation. This has led me to ask, what is the proper way to refer to the SQL extension used by Access?

I've seen casual references to "Jet SQL" and "Access SQL," but I'm not confident that these are official or up-to-date.

Comment: `Jet SQL` is more right than `Access SQL` at least. Although depending on the version of access you are using you might be using an `ACE` database engine

Comment: @Brad +1 on your comment. I agree with your point, but now that "Jet" is officially deprecated and "ACE" is strongly tied to Access I've been leaning toward "Access SQL" as a way to identify the dialect while avoiding the whole Jet-vs-ACE (i.e., old-vs-new) issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft Corporation refers to it as "Microsoft Access SQL" in an Access 2013 [help article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff844937(v=office.15).aspx):

> "Microsoft Access database engine SQL is generally ANSI-89 Level 1 compliant. However, certain ANSI SQL features are not implemented in Microsoft Access SQL. Conversely, Microsoft Access SQL includes reserved words and features not supported in ANSI SQL."
>
> -- *Comparison of Microsoft Access SQL and ANSI SQL (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff844937(v=office.15).aspx)*

Comment: If someone can identify a more-recent reference, e.g., one for Access 2010 or 2013, please comment or post a new answer. Thanks.

Comment: From Office Dev Center for Office 2013: [Microsoft Access SQL reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn123881(v=office.15).aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft seems to call it 'Microsoft Jet SQL': http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/access-help/comparison-of-microsoft-jet-sql-and-ansi-sql-HP001032250.aspx?CTT=1

Comment: +1 for the reference, but it refers to Access 2003 and therefore pre-dates the Jet/ACE era. Lately I've been calling it "Access SQL", but I'll be interested to see if there is a more appropriate moniker.

Comment: Thanks, [Yawar](http://stackoverflow.com/users/20371/yawar). I agree with [Gord](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2144390/gord-thompson) that the article you referenced refers back to a much older version. But, your link led me to an Access 2007 [article](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/comparison-of-microsoft-access-sql-and-ansi-sql-HA001231436.aspx) that calls it "Access SQL." This is pretty darn close. Thanks for leading me in the right direction!