# MS Access SQL : INSERT and INNER JOIN on multiple tables gives missing operator error

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access, inner-join, sql-insert

I'm new to MS Access SQL and I am trying to `JOIN` three tables to `INSERT` a bunch of IDs into another table.

The query I have at the moment is:

```
INSERT INTO FixturePlayers (FixtureId, PlayerId, TeamId, [Position] )
   SELECT 
      tempFixtureSquad.FixtureId,  Players.PlayerId,  Teams.TeamId, 
      tempFixtureSquad.Position
   FROM 
      tempFixtureSquad
   INNER JOIN 
      Players ON tempFixtureSquad.FirstName =  Players.FirstName 
              AND tempFixtureSquad.LastName = Players.LastName
   INNER JOIN 
      Teams ON tempFixtureSquad.Team = Teams.Team
```

But when I try to save this, Access says:

> Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression ".

Which means sweet nada to me! It even looks like a nonsense message. There is a single `"` just plonked there at the end... There are no `"` in my query. and as far as I can tell there doesn't need to be.

Table `tempFixtureSquad` has columns `ID` (the PK), `FixtureId`, `Team` (the team name), `Position`, `FirstName` (string) and `LastName` (string)

So I need to `JOIN` this table to tables `Players` and `Teams` to get the `ID` for the player and team for each record in the `tempFixtureSquad` table as the `FixturePlayers` table it needs inserting into uses only ID's and has no string columns (columns from that table are listed in the `INSERT INTO` clause)

What am I doing wrong? Ta

Comment: Hmmm, think maybe I need some brackets on that FROM and JOINS?

Comment: I am honestly sorry that you must use MS Access.  I've been there and it's not a fun place.  It's like Microsoft decide that regular SQL was too hard (false), so they decided to give Access it's own dialect...

Comment: Note: The term "MS SQL" is often used for Microsoft SQL Server, so that would be a bit misleading in this case. The term for the SQL dialect used in Access seems to be "Microsoft Access SQL": http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22666449/what-is-the-proper-way-to-refer-to-the-sql-dialect-used-by-microsoft-access

Comment: @openwonk Thanks for the sympathy, I cant flippin stand the thing but helping a mate out... half my battle comes from it being nearly 10 yrs since I last opened Access. For which I am thankful.

Comment: @Guffa, exactly what I meant implicitly.  Thanks for making this explicit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding parentheses:

```
FROM (tempFixtureSquad INNER JOIN Players ON tempFixtureSquad.FirstName = Players.FirstName AND tempFixtureSquad.LastName = Players.LastName) INNER JOIN Teams ON tempFixtureSquad.Team = Teams.Team
```

Comment: Thanks, that works for the two joins. But If I add a third and continue the brackets idea get `Syntax error in JOIN operation`. These error messages are not the most helpful things ever...

Comment: Ah, I had misspelled a table name also. Boom.

Comment: Please show code.  If I had a dime for every time I saw those useless error messages....